# jQuery can't cache IDs

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to cache my jQuery IDs like this:
This works perfect just as I want it to:

```
var myid = $("#myid");
myid.hide();
```

This example also works:

```
var n = 4;
$("#myid"+n).show();
```

But when I try to do this, it won't work:
What I'm doing wrong?

```
var myid = $("#myid");
var n = 4;
myid+n.show();
```

Comment: `myid` is a (jQuery) object. You are trying to add the number `4` to an object. That's just not how things work. Look what happens when you are trying to add a number to an object: `console.log({} + 4); // [object Object]4`. You get back the **string** `"[object Object]4"`.

Comment: You are trying to add 4 to $("myid") which is an object. which returns "[object, Object]4".

Comment: Why, if the second code snippet _works_, would you want to use the third (or something like it)? This sort of thing usually leads to identifying an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Because the way how JS works, parrenties are validated first, js parser encounters "#myId" which is a string and concats n to it, at the end would be $("#myid4") and then it looks up for a element with that id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Try this insted.

var myid = "#myid";
var n = 4;
$(myid+n).show();
```

Comment: Tarid, I like your solution. It works perfect. Also thanks to all other help I got. I understand now how this works.

Answer (score 1):

The result of `$(...)` is an object, not a string. What you're doing in your third example is essentially as follows:

```
$(...) + 4;
```

That's nonsense.  In JavasScript, you can think about an object as a JSON construct.  What would you expect from the following:

```
var v = { "foo":"bar", "baz":4 }
v + 4;
```

If you need a dynamically located ID, use your second method only.

Answer (score 0):

With your current operation you are basically adding an object and a number which will give you a `string` and `string` does not have the function `show` which will lead to an `error`.

If you need to store the id in a variable, then you can store the complete id in there and use it in your code.

e.g.

```
var myid = "#myid";
var n = 4;
$(myid + n).show();
```

or

```
var myid = "myid";
var n = 4;
$("#"+ myid + n).show();
```